# WebdriverIO v8 - Import Element commands

Tags: webdriver-io

With the WebdriverIo v7 I was able to import the element commands like "click" and others using the following import:

`import * as element from 'webdriverio/build/commands/element';`

With v8 it seems to be not possible any more as the exports were re-organized. At least I'm getting the `[ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath "./build/commands/element" is not defined by "exports"` error when trying to use the import above.

I wonder if there is still a way to directly import and override the element commands like "click"?

I need the "click" command available in order to monkey patch it (I know it is something to avoid, but I need to do that for an experimental purpose) and then rolling the behaivor of "click" back to default in runtime after some particular part of the automated test is over.

With v8 it looks like the command overriding may only be achieved with the `overwriteCommand` API and the overwrite part works fine for my use case, yet I'm not sure implementing the rollback will be that straightforward.

With v7 I was able to import the "click" command (as a function), store it in variable and then assign it back to the element to perform the rollback.